# Get beacon button click (react native)

Tags: react-native, beacon

I need to use a beacon button as a panic button in a React Native application. So, I need to identify when the user clicks the beacon button. Is that possible? Is there any library that can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a clickable hardware beacon that turns on when you click on it, you can write an app so that it performs some "panic" procedure when that beacon is detected.

For ReactNative, try this package:

https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager